# InvalidSessionDescriptionError: Answer changes mid for level, was '3', now '0'

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc

I'm currently developing a WebRTC app and everything worked fine until I recently got this error, when starting a videochat:

> InvalidSessionDescriptionError: Answer changes mid for level, was '3',
>   now '0'

I really don't know what's wrong since it worked fine some weeks ago and I didn't change the code...
Any ideas how to solve this issue??

Edit: Interestingly, I don't get the error when calling from...
...Chrome (Windows) to Firefox (Windows)
...Firefox (Android) to Chrome (Windows)
...Chrome (Android) to Firefox (Windows)
...Firefox (Android) to Firefox (Windows)

Other combinations lead to the error described above, except for calling from Chrome to Chrome, which doesn't work but also doesn't show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome://webrtc-internals and look for the SDP both in setLocalDescription and setRemoteDescription. The error you mention typically occurs if the a=mid lines do not match.